# how can i persist a model between multiple activities in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, model-view-controller, model

I'm a beginner to android development, and I'm trying to write my code in an MVC pattern, but I'm having trouble understanding how a model would work. As far as I can tell every time you start a new activity with an intent you are not able to pass a model along with it. As far as i can tell you'd have to reinitialize it each time you start a new activity. Am I missing something? I looked into Parcelable, but it seems that you loose your methods if you make your model Parcelable. right now I'm building a log in system, which checks my local sqllite db on start up if the user has already logged in, and if so it passes to another activity, otherwise it passes to the log in activity, but I wan't to keep that user model alive through all the activities. Is thee a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to also consider keeping a static reference around to the model data that you want to share across activities so that you don't have to keep serializing/deserializing the model when switching between activities. You can get away with using Parcelable if your models are small, but at some point, performance may become an issue.

I'm working on a project where we keep the models in a Singleton that we can access throughout the app, and although I generally hate Singleton's for how they can make unit testing more difficult, I have found this approach to perform better with larger models than trying to rely on Android's serialization mechanism.

Here's is a very rough example of what I mean (disclaimer: I have not actually run tested this code, but I hope this illustrates the concept):

You might have a singleton class that I terribly called Models

```
public class Models {

    private static Models instance;

    private boolean isInitialized = false;

    private User user;
    private OtherInterestingModel otherInterestingModel;

    private Models() {
    }

    public static synchronized Models getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Models();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void loadModels() {
        if (!isInitialized) {
            /*
             *  One-time model initialization here.
             */
            isInitialized = true;
        }
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public OtherInterestingModel getOtherInterestingModel() {
        return otherInterestingModel;
    }
}
```

In your LoginActivity, you can initialize the Models class, say, in your onCreate():

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Models.getInstance().loadModels();

        User user = Models.getInstance().getUser();
        OtherInterestingModelData otherData = Models.getInstance().getOtherInterestingModel();

        // Do something with the model data...
    }

    /*
     * This might be called after the user enters data and clicks a login button...
     */
    private void login() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, AwesomeLoggedInActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Once the user successfully logs into your app, you could have basically the same code in your main activity:

```
public class AwesomeLoggedInActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Models.getInstance().loadModels();

        User user = Models.getInstance().getUser();
        OtherInterestingModelData otherData = Models.getInstance().getOtherInterestingModel();

        // Do something with the model data...
    }
}
```

Notice that by having a Singleton, you avoided having to serialize the model data by passing it through the intent that started the main activity.

Comment: very interesting... off the top of your head can you show me an example of this? or at least point me in the right direction of how to implement something like that?

Comment: very nice. this implementation defiantly makes more sense for large amounts of data. thanks for the example code... that helped a lot. and in many ways it seems much more easy to implement.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that with the `Parcelable` interface.

You do not lose your class's methods when you implement the `Parcelable` interface. The interface simply defines a method for writing your member variables to a `Parcel` object when you need to pass the object around.

Once you retrieve the data from your Intent via `getParcelableExtra()`, the object is recreated from the `Parcel` and you can once again treat it as an instance of whatever class it is.

For example, if you have a `User` class that extends `Parcelable`, you can bundle it with an Intent by calling `putExtra("user", myUser)`. `myUser` is then (behind the scenes) packed into a Parcel and attached to the Intent. In your next Activity, you can retrieve that User object with `User myUser = (User) getParcelableExtra("user");`, and the Parcel will be unpacked and returned to you. You wil once again have a fully functioning User object.